# Doxygen not picking up comments

Tags: c#, doxygen

I've been trying to put comments into my file so give more detailed information of functions and such but doxygen hasn't been registering any of my comments. I was why this was. Here is what I have been putting in my code

```html
/*!* comment1 */
 public Texture whiteAsteroid;
 public Texture redAsteroid;
 public Texture yellowAsteroid;
 public Texture blueAsteroid;

 public GameObject particleDeathEffect;

 private bool whiteCollison;
 private bool redCollison;
 /*!* comment2 */
 private bool yellowCollison;
 private bool blueCollison;

 /*!* comment3 */
 void Start ()
 {
  // sets the rotate speed to random value
  rotateSpeed = Random.Range (2f, 5f);
  /*!* comment4 */
  size = Random.Range (3f, 10f);
  transform.localScale = new Vector3 (size, 1, size);
```

comment1 appears just fine but none of the others do. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: add a language tag, please.

Comment: @mjuarez: doxygen is a better `javadoc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private element comments do not appear in doxygen by default.

Set `EXTRACT_PRIVATE`. http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_private